# the missing value in firebase setValue methode Prevents from setting the other values in DataBase

Tags: ios, swift, database, authentication, setvalue

when the user sign up firebase authenticate the user and Upload his values like username and email and Profile Image but if he skip the Profile Image the user Will pass the auth and his email registered but firebase will not set the username and email and dismiss the profile image

```
@IBAction func SignUp(_ sender: Any) {
        if  username.text != "", email.text != "", password.text != "", fullname.text != "" {

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message:".Fill all fields\n .User do exists\n .Network error ")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    return
                }
                let uid = user?.uid
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://........com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
                if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1){
                    storageRef.putData( imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            return
                        }
                        let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        let ref = Database.database().reference()
                        let usersReferance = ref.child("users")
                        let newUserReferance = usersReferance.child(self.username.text!).child(uid!)
                        newUserReferance.setValue(["fullname": self.fullname.text, "username": self.username.text, "email": self.email.text, "password": self.password.text, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
                    })
                }
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the values to the different fields outside the image checker closure or they won't set if selectedImage is nil.

```
@IBAction func SignUp(_ sender: Any) {
if  username.text != "", email.text != "", password.text != "", fullname.text != "" {

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message:".Fill all fields\n .User do exists\n .Network error ")
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            return
        }
        let uid = user?.uid

        var userValues = [
            "fullname": self.fullname.text,
            "username": self.username.text,
            "email": self.email.text,
            "password": self.password.text
        ]

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://........com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1){
            storageRef.putData( imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }
                let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                userValues["profileImageUrl"] = profileImageUrl

                setData(userValues, uid!)
            })
        } else {
            setData(userValues, uid!)
        }



        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })
}
}

func setData(_ data: [String: Any], uid: Int) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReferance = ref.child("users")
    let newUserReferance = usersReferance.child(data["username"]).child(uid)
    newUserReferance.setValue(data)
}
```

You should use a function to store the data too because the putData of the image is asyncronous.

Comment: i don't think this is the right way change all my and separate the hole code and creat a func

Comment: If you set the values inside the image "if let" that code will never execute if self.selectedImage is nil.

Comment: userValues?    do you mean I set it??  I have tried your method but i get some errors i will pass this problem by forcing the user to chose PF image